# Object detection methodologies

Tags: c, image-processing

I have an assignment of object detection. 
I have googled but I didn't find all object detection methods.

Can anyone show me all the methods of object detection?

Comment: Sorry about my english & my question. I just ask that I want to know all of method about object detection. I haved googled, there are some methods but there is no summary report. So I need a statistics about all method about object detection

Comment: A simple api you can use for object detection it uses resnet https://rapidapi.com/mantis-object-detection-mantis-object-detection-default/api/mantis-object-detection/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For starters, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785419/detection-of-coins-and-fit-ellipses-on-an-image).

Then Google around (I'm sorry, you've said you've tried, but I just don't believe that a Google search on [object detection](http://www.google.com/search?q=object+detection) gave you **zero** useful results).  Look up things you're not sure about on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page).  Finally, refine your question to be directed at a specific issue.  You'll get a lot more useful input that way, and you'll learn more, too.

I don't think anyone here would indulge in teaching you **all** methods of object detection.  To put it bluntly, you're simply **asking for too much**.

Comment: Sorry about my english & my question. I just ask that I want to know all of method about object detection. I haved googled, there are some methods but there is no summary report. So I need a statistics about all method about object detection.

Comment: Your English is fine, don't worry.  The problem is: it sounds you're asking somebody here to write the edge detection method summary for you.  All the information you need for that summary is available freely on the internet -- you've already said that you've found *some* techniques.  All you have to do is put some time into finding the info and collating it.  Wikipedia is always a good place to start.

Comment: thanks your suggest and your link. I have found somethings interesting. And I know that i have to has my own summary.

Comment: You're welcome.  Spend some time looking around and come back when you have a specific question.  Good luck.