# OpenCV: Dominoes circular spots/disks detection

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am developing an Android app that calculates the sum of all points of the being-seen dominoes pieces -shown in picture- using OpenCV for Android.

[image: a sample]

The problem is, I can't find a way to filtering other contours and counting only dots I see in the dominoes, I tried to use Canny edge finding then use HoughCircles, but with no result, as I don't have an absolute top view of the rocks and HoughCircles detect perfect circles only :)

Here is my code:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
    inputFrame.copyTo(mRgba);

    Mat grey = new Mat();
    // Make it greyscale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, grey, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

    // init contours arraylist
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(200);     

    //blur
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grey, grey, new Size(9,9), 10);        
    Imgproc.threshold(grey, grey, 80, 150, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);


    // because findContours modifies the image I back it up
    Mat greyCopy = new Mat();
    grey.copyTo(greyCopy);


    Imgproc.findContours(greyCopy, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);      
    // Now I have my controus pefectly


    MatOfPoint2f mMOP2f1 = new MatOfPoint2f();

    //a list for only selected contours
    List<MatOfPoint> SelectedContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(400);     

    for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
    {

        if(here I should put a condition that distinguishes my spots, eg: if contour inside is black and is a black disk)
        {
            SelectedContours.add(contours.get(i));
        }
    }
    Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, SelectedContours, -1, new Scalar(255,0,0,255), 1);       
    return mRgba;        
}
```

EDIT:

One unique feature of my contours after threshold is they're totally black from inside, is there anyway I could calculate the mean color/intensity for a given contour ?

Answer (score 5):

There is a similiar problem and possible solution on SO, titled [Detection of coins (and fit ellipses) on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785419/detection-of-coins-and-fit-ellipses-on-an-image). Here you will find some recomendations about opencv's function `fitEllipse`.

You should take a look at [this for more info on opencv's function `fitEllipse`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-fitellipse).

Also, to detect only black elements in an image, you can use HSV color model, to find only black colors. You can [find an explanation here](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/).