# fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: OpenCV ellipse detection in Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing, javacv

We tried to convert the c++ Code from [Detection of coins (and fit ellipses) on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785419/detection-of-coins-and-fit-ellipses-on-an-image) into Java. After solving the first problem in the thread [Problems with OpenCV ellipse detection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962234/problems-with-opencv-ellipse-detection-in-java/21962374?noredirect=1#comment33277673_21962374), starting the program with the parameters

```
2 PathToThePicture
```

leads to following fatal error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005addc330, pid=1700, tid=1472
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x3c330]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# PathToTheProject\hs_err_pid1700.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Error report:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x670d26df, pid=2832, tid=5672
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x26df]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x004eb800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5672, stack(0x00570000,0x005c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x005bfb7c, ECX=0x00000016, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x005bfaf4, EBP=0x005bfb18, ESI=0x004eb930, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x670d26df, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x005bfaf4)
0x005bfaf4:   00000000 670c1eb2 00000000 00000000
0x005bfb04:   00000058 004eb800 34a45f90 34a45f90
0x005bfb14:   004eb930 005bfb60 0226a9dd 004eb930
0x005bfb24:   005bfb68 005bfb7c 00000000 00000058
0x005bfb34:   00000000 004ec15c 004ec15c 005bfb40
0x005bfb44:   34a45f90 005bfb7c 34aaf550 00000000
0x005bfb54:   34a45f90 00000000 005bfb70 005bfba0
0x005bfb64:   0226339a 24ef55f8 022688e6 00000058 

Instructions: (pc=0x670d26df)
0x670d26bf:   83 c7 01 83 e9 01 75 f6 8b c8 c1 e0 08 03 c1 8b
0x670d26cf:   c8 c1 e0 10 03 c1 8b ca 83 e2 03 c1 e9 02 74 06
0x670d26df:   f3 ab 85 d2 74 0a 88 07 83 c7 01 83 ea 01 75 f6
0x670d26ef:   8b 44 24 08 5f c3 8b 44 24 04 c3 90 90 90 90 90 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x005bfb7c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x004eb800
ECX=0x00000016 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x005bfaf4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x004eb800
EBP=0x005bfb18 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x004eb800
ESI=0x004eb930 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00570000,0x005c0000],  sp=0x005bfaf4,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x26df]
j  com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer.memset(Lcom/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer;IJ)Lcom/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer;+0
j  com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer.fill(I)Lcom/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer;+107
j  com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer.zero()Lcom/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer;+2
j  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvSeq.<init>()V+9
j  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvContour.<init>()V+1
j  Dieter.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+67
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x13f35a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x202c6e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x13f3dd]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc9945]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd45e7]
C  [javaw.exe+0x2070]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa5b1]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa63b]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x1495d]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x498ee]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x498c4]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer.memset(Lcom/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer;IJ)Lcom/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer;+0
j  com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer.fill(I)Lcom/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer;+107
j  com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer.zero()Lcom/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer;+2
j  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvSeq.<init>()V+9
j  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvContour.<init>()V+1
j  Dieter.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+67
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00826800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7436, stack(0x044e0000,0x04530000)]
  0x00820c00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6644, stack(0x04450000,0x044a0000)]
  0x0081fc00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1156, stack(0x043c0000,0x04410000)]
  0x0081c800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1820, stack(0x04330000,0x04380000)]
  0x007b0400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5456, stack(0x042a0000,0x042f0000)]
  0x007ae800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2588, stack(0x00de0000,0x00e30000)]
=>0x004eb800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5672, stack(0x00570000,0x005c0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x007ad400 VMThread [stack: 0x00d50000,0x00da0000] [id=3176]
  0x0083e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x04570000,0x045c0000] [id=4452]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 1323K [0x24a20000, 0x24f70000, 0x29f70000)
  eden space 4416K,  18% used [0x24a20000, 0x24aeafe8, 0x24e70000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x24ef0000, 0x24f70000, 0x24f70000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24e70000, 0x24e70000, 0x24ef0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 370K [0x29f70000, 0x2aa20000, 0x34a20000)
   the space 10944K,   3% used [0x29f70000, 0x29fccb38, 0x29fccc00, 0x2aa20000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 912K [0x34a20000, 0x35620000, 0x38a20000)
   the space 12288K,   7% used [0x34a20000, 0x34b04270, 0x34b04400, 0x35620000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x38a20000, 0x38e52050, 0x38e52200, 0x39420000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x39420000, 0x39a66800, 0x39a66800, 0x3a020000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00c40000,0x00cf0000] byte_map_base: 0x00b1af00

Polling page: 0x004c0000

Code Cache  [0x02260000, 0x02320000, 0x04260000)
 total_blobs=266 nmethods=113 adapters=90 free_code_cache=32016Kb largest_free_block=32785344

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.214 Thread 0x00820c00  108             java.util.AbstractList$Itr::hasNext (20 bytes)
Event: 0.214 Thread 0x00820c00 nmethod 108 0x02319d48 code [0x02319e50, 0x02319f0c]
Event: 0.215 Thread 0x00820c00  110             com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader$ClassProperties::addAll (183 bytes)
Event: 0.216 Thread 0x00820c00 nmethod 110 0x0231a248 code [0x0231a490, 0x0231ac68]
Event: 0.216 Thread 0x00820c00  111             java.lang.String::indexOf (25 bytes)
Event: 0.216 Thread 0x00820c00 nmethod 111 0x0231b488 code [0x0231b590, 0x0231b65c]
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x00820c00  112             java.lang.Character::toLowerCase (6 bytes)
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x00820c00 nmethod 112 0x0231b748 code [0x0231b850, 0x0231b8f8]
Event: 0.218 Thread 0x00820c00  113             java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator::hasMoreElements (53 bytes)
Event: 0.218 Thread 0x00820c00 nmethod 113 0x0231b988 code [0x0231ba80, 0x0231bb60]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 0.204 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4416K [0x24a20000, 0x24f70000, 0x29f70000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x24a20000, 0x24e70000, 0x24e70000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x24e70000, 0x24e70000, 0x24ef0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24ef0000, 0x24ef0000, 0x24f70000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x29f70000, 0x2aa20000, 0x34a20000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x29f70000, 0x29f70000, 0x29f70200, 0x2aa20000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 887K [0x34a20000, 0x35620000, 0x38a20000)
   the space 12288K,   7% used [0x34a20000, 0x34afdfc8, 0x34afe000, 0x35620000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x38a20000, 0x38e52050, 0x38e52200, 0x39420000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x39420000, 0x39a66800, 0x39a66800, 0x3a020000)
Event: 0.206 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 512K [0x24a20000, 0x24f70000, 0x29f70000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x24a20000, 0x24a20000, 0x24e70000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x24ef0000, 0x24f70000, 0x24f70000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24e70000, 0x24e70000, 0x24ef0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 370K [0x29f70000, 0x2aa20000, 0x34a20000)
   the space 10944K,   3% used [0x29f70000, 0x29fccb38, 0x29fccc00, 0x2aa20000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 887K [0x34a20000, 0x35620000, 0x38a20000)
   the space 12288K,   7% used [0x34a20000, 0x34afdfc8, 0x34afe000, 0x35620000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x38a20000, 0x38e52050, 0x38e52200, 0x39420000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x39420000, 0x39a66800, 0x39a66800, 0x3a020000)
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.177 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24e2f6d8 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.177 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24e33ec8 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.203 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24e569d8 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.206 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24a27c80 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.207 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24a2ad28 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.207 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24a2dc90 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.207 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24a314d0 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.208 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24a5f148 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.216 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24acf300 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x004eb800 Threw 0x24ad3248 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.207 loading class 0x0462fa78
Event: 0.207 loading class 0x0462fa78 done
Event: 0.208 loading class 0x0462fe38
Event: 0.208 loading class 0x0462fe38 done
Event: 0.216 loading class 0x0083ef48
Event: 0.216 loading class 0x0083ef48 done
Event: 0.217 loading class 0x0083f338
Event: 0.217 loading class 0x0083f338 done
Event: 0.218 loading class 0x3a040448
Event: 0.218 loading class 0x3a040448 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00e30000 - 0x00e5f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x76ed0000 - 0x77038000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x74b20000 - 0x74c60000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x751e0000 - 0x752af000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x69530000 - 0x695ca000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x64c10000 - 0x64e62000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcGenral.DLL
0x74f90000 - 0x7504e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
0x74ae0000 - 0x74b1e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x74900000 - 0x7491d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x76bd0000 - 0x76c11000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x73df0000 - 0x73ecc000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\UxTheme.dll
0x74ca0000 - 0x74def000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll
0x76a10000 - 0x76b18000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
0x73a30000 - 0x73a50000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x73c70000 - 0x73c82000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\samcli.dll
0x76c70000 - 0x76d7b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll
0x74a40000 - 0x74ac7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x731a0000 - 0x731b5000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSACM32.dll
0x74880000 - 0x74888000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x75860000 - 0x76a03000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll
0x739c0000 - 0x739d9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x739f0000 - 0x73a09000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x73210000 - 0x73334000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
0x75060000 - 0x750d7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x74820000 - 0x7487e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x67500000 - 0x67514000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x752b0000 - 0x75361000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
0x748f0000 - 0x748f9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x75380000 - 0x754ce000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x73a10000 - 0x73a30000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x74050000 - 0x7405e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x72e30000 - 0x73047000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
0x72c60000 - 0x72e24000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WININET.dll
0x74890000 - 0x748e1000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x74f40000 - 0x74f7a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x74800000 - 0x7481f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x74060000 - 0x740d7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.DLL
0x74920000 - 0x74945000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x750e0000 - 0x751d7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll
0x74450000 - 0x74635000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.16384_none_a9f4965301334e09\COMCTL32.dll
0x670d0000 - 0x6718f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x64f80000 - 0x65300000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x74040000 - 0x74048000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x749a0000 - 0x749a6000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL
0x76c20000 - 0x76c6d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll
0x74f80000 - 0x74f87000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll
0x66ba0000 - 0x66bac000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x66b80000 - 0x66ba0000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x66b60000 - 0x66b73000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x66910000 - 0x66979000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100.dll
0x70fc0000 - 0x71ef6000     C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_ffmpeg248.dll
0x64a00000 - 0x64c06000     C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_core248.dll
0x64790000 - 0x649fb000     C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_imgproc248.dll
0x64580000 - 0x64787000     C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_highgui248.dll
0x66d80000 - 0x66d99000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AVIFIL32.dll
0x67490000 - 0x674b2000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVFW32.dll
0x66d60000 - 0x66d74000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AVICAP32.dll
0x670c0000 - 0x670cf000     F:\tmp\javacpp367334687899361\jniopencv_highgui.dll
0x66810000 - 0x66885000     F:\tmp\javacpp367334687899361\jniopencv_core.dll
0x72260000 - 0x723a8000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: DetectEllipse 2 PathToPicture
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;F:\Programmieren\tools\eclipse 32bit;
USERNAME=Username
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8 , 64 bit Build 9200 

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, erms, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 8325332k(5583064k free), swap 13445332k(10026960k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_51-b13), built on Dec 18 2013 19:09:58 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Sun Feb 23 01:12:58 2014
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Here is the converted Java-Code:

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_FILLED;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_RGB;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_WHOLE_SEQ;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvCreateImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvCreateMemStorage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvDrawContours;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvGetSize;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvPoint;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvScalar;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvXorS;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvZero;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_RETR_CCOMP;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_THRESH_BINARY;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvContourArea;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvDilate;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvFindContours;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvThreshold;

import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvContour;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvMemStorage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvRect;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvScalar;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvSeq;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class DetectEllipse{

    public static final double M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
    public static final double MIN_AREA = 100.00;
    public static final double MAX_TOL = 100.00;

    private static int[] array = { 0 };
    //
    // We need this to be high enough to get rid of things that are too small
    // too
    // have a definite shape. Otherwise, they will end up as ellipse false
    // positives.
    //
    //
    // One way to tell if an object is an ellipse is to look at the relationship
    // of its area to its dimensions. If its actual occupied area can be
    // estimated
    // using the well-known area formula Area = PI*A*B, then it has a good
    // chance of
    // being an ellipse.
    //
    // This value is the maximum permissible error between actual and estimated
    // area.
    //

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          IplImage src = cvLoadImage(args[1], 0);
          if (src == null) {
             System.out.println("!!! Unable to load image: " + args[1]);
             return;
          }
        // the first command line parameter must be file name of binary
        // (black-n-white) image
        if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) == 2) {
            IplImage dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), 8, 3);
            CvMemStorage storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
            CvSeq contour = new CvContour();
            // maybe: = new CvSeq(0)
            cvThreshold(src, src, 1, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
            //
            // Invert the image such that white is foreground, black is
            // background.
            // Dilate to get rid of noise.
            //
            cvXorS(src, cvScalar(255, 0, 0, 0), src, null);
            cvDilate(src, src, null, 2);

            cvFindContours(src, storage, contour,
                    Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_CCOMP,
                    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0, 0));
            cvZero(dst);

            for (; contour.flags() != 0; contour = contour.h_next()) {
                // if not working: use contour.isNull()
                double actual_area = Math.abs(cvContourArea(contour,
                        CV_WHOLE_SEQ, 0));
                if (actual_area < MIN_AREA)
                    continue;

                //
                // FIXME:
                // Assuming the axes of the ellipse are vertical/perpendicular.
                //
                CvRect rect = ((CvContour) contour).rect();
                int A = rect.width() / 2;
                int B = rect.height() / 2;
                double estimated_area = Math.PI * A * B;
                double error = Math.abs(actual_area - estimated_area);
                if (error > MAX_TOL)
                    continue;
                System.out.printf("center x: %d y: %d A: %d B: %d\n", rect.x()
                        + A, rect.y() + B, A, B);

                CvScalar color = CV_RGB(
                        tangible.RandomNumbers.nextNumber() % 255,
                        tangible.RandomNumbers.nextNumber() % 255,
                        tangible.RandomNumbers.nextNumber() % 255);
                cvDrawContours(dst, contour, color, color, -1, CV_FILLED, 8,
                        cvPoint(0, 0));
            }

            cvSaveImage("coins.png", dst, array);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's important that you debug the code to figure line which line is responsible for the crash. Report back when you have this info!

Comment: The line `cvThreshold(src, src, 1, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);` is responsible for the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvThreshold()` expects a **single channel** image, and you are telling it to store the result in a **3-channel** image, hence the crash!

You can call `cvCreateImage()` to create a single channel `IplImage`.

Good luck!